# Change the value of static variable

Tags: java, date, static-variables

I want to set the variable of the `monthBtn`, and by calling a function it will change the variable of the month.

```
private static String monthBtn;

    public static String getCurrentMonth() {
        int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String monthBtn= "//*[@text='"+month+"']";
        System.out.println(yearBtn);
        return monthBtn;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getCurrentMonth();
        System.out.println("Xpath Year ="+monthBtn);
    }
```

When I ran this code the value of variable `monthBtn` return null value, but my expect condition is `//*[@text='07']`

Comment: By typing `String monthBtn= "//*[@text='"+month+"']";` you declared *local* varriable called `monthBtn`. You can address your static varriable by name `monthBtn=...` if no local varriable declared or by class name `MyClass.monthBtn = ...`

https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 problems with your code.

1. the "month" that Calendar.get(MONTH) returns is not the numeric month, but one of the constants defined in Calendar class. For example, for the month of JULY it returns `6`. You should ideally migrate to using the modern classes defined in `java.time`, such as LocalDate, that don't behave in surprising ways.
2. Formatting. An `int` does not have leading zeros. But you can use `String.format` to zero-pad it.
3. Variable visibility. You are declaring a local `monthBtn` variable that hides the static variable with the same name.

You can get around these problems by changing the code in your method to:

```
    int month = LocalDate.now().getMonthValue();
    monthBtn = String.format("//*[@text='%02d']", month);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String monthBtn;

public static String getCurrentMonth() {
    int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    monthBtn= "//*[@text='"+month+"']"; //you should assign value to the class member, in your code you were declaring local variable.
    System.out.println(yearBtn);
    return monthBtn;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = getCurrentMonth(); //you should store the value returned in some variable
    System.out.println("Xpath Year ="+str); //here you were referring to the class member `monthBtn` variable, which is null, and now you take the local str value.
}
```

I hope you understand now why you get `null`. You have local variables and the return value of `getCurrentMonth()` isn't stored anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Update your code like below. You are creating local Variable of the same name and not assigning value to static variable. Also if you are expecting the it Calender.MONTH will give current , it is not the case . Since months start from 0. So if current month is July, you will get 6 and not 7

```
private static String monthBtn;

public static String getCurrentMonth() {
    int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    monthBtn= "//*[@text='"+month+"']";
    return monthBtn;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getCurrentMonth();
    System.out.println("Xpath Year ="+monthBtn);
}
```

Comment: Okay , downvote is welcome , what is the reason , please specify